# Por que começar um título com a preposição "de"?

Tags: significado, preposições, semântica, literatura

Ao ler o livro "O Silmarillion", de J. R. R. Tolkien, percebi que, no conto "*Quenta Silmarillion*", a maioria dos subtítulos começam com a preposição "de". Alguns exemplos (em ordem de aparição no livro):

1. **Do** Princípio dos Dias
2. **De** Aulë e Yavanna
3. **Da** Vinda dos Elfos e do Cativeiro de Melkor
4. **De** Thingol e Melian

Entre outros.

Fiquei na dúvida em relação à necessidade da preposição "de" nessa situação. Há alguma diferença, por exemplo, entre "Do Princípio dos Dias" para "O Princípio dos Dias"?

Comment: Vem do Latim, nos títulos, quer dizer. sobre um assunto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse "de" provavelmente significa "sobre", e sua adoção costuma carregar uma diferença sutil.

Enquanto "O Princípio dos Dias" pode sugerir uma obra exaustiva sobre o princípio dos dias, "Do Princípio dos Dias" = "Sobre o Princípio dos Dias" sugere apenas uma discussão/descrição relacionada ao tema.

Ou ainda, como comenta Lambie em sua [resposta](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/337084) a uma pergunta quase idêntica em inglês ([*What is role of the word “of” at the beginning of a title?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/337077)), pode existir um "Uma história", "Um tratado" ou "Um ensaio" implícito quando se começa com "De". Obervação que é relevante aqui, dado que o título [no original é](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Quenta_Silmarillion) "***Of** the Beginning of Days*", e "*of*" [significa](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/of) também "*With reference to; **about**;  In respect to*".

Outra palavra para "sobre" em inglês é "*on*", e portanto as respostas e comentários à pergunta "[Why do the titles of scholarly works sometimes begin with the word “on”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/402576) também são relevantes aqui. O usuário tchrist, em particular, imediatamente comenta:

> I'll bet that the real reason is because all the medieval scholarly texts had titles in Latin that began "De ...." to mean "about" or "regarding" or "on the matter of".

(Tradução livre: Aposto que a razão de verdade é porque todos os textos medievais acadêmicos tinham títulos em latim que começavam "De ....", significando "sobre" ou "referente a" ou "com relação ".)

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a preposição neste caso é um recurso estilístico, podia-se omitir ou usar outra palavra no seu lugar. Repare-se que a presença da preposição é mais elegante do que a sua ausência. Em sentido prático as palavras alternativas todas seriam mais longas, com mais letras.

Este uso é muito comum em determinados círculos principalmente nos ensaístas, na filosofia e nos campos das ciências sociais.

O seu uso indica uma elaboração sobre o assunto enquanto a sua ausência deixaria só um título de nomes próprios, ou uma determinada acção *"Vinda dos"*, *"Cativeiro de"*, nos exemplos dados. Deste modo, a inclusão da preposição sugere um sentido de elaboração e parte, enquanto a sua ausência deixaria um sentido mais assertivo, factual ou descritivo.

Em termos literários ambos os usos emprestam uma força própria muito diferente ao título e a prevalência do seu uso tem variado com as épocas. Penso que os meados dos séc.XX foram um ponto alto na frequência da opção pela preposição (não tenho dados concretos para apoiar esta afirmação, mas os leitores ávidos decerto terão reparado na tendência.)

Comment: @LuizFelipe eu ainda quero ler as gramáticas a ver se encontro algum comentário sobre este uso. Caso eu encontre edito a resposta para incluir a citaçãoe e fonte.

Answer (score 0):

Penso que a "stafusa" fornece uma excelente resposta. Em inglês, começamos uma frase com a palavra "of".

Exemplo:
Of the men who went into battle; they were all slain.

Penso que o autor fez uma tentativa deliberada de acrescentar um nível de antiguidade para que o texto soasse mais antigo do que 1970.

I think that "stafusa" provides an excellent answer. In English we do start a sentence with the word "of".

Example:
Of the men who went into battle; they were all slain.

I think that the author made a deliberate attempt to add a level of antiquity to make the text sound older than 1970.